# Django 1.8: non-deterministic "FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword" on related_name

Tags: python, django

I sometimes (once per a couple months) get a problem with a reverse lookup on a ForeignKey relation that suddenly stops working. The FK field is on a dynamically created model (created only once on startup, by a custom model metaclass). Here is the line responsible for the FK field:

`'tag': models.ForeignKey(model, related_name='items')`

(one field on an `attrs` dict passed as the third argument to `type` constructor).

The FieldError is raised by queries like `Tag.objects.filter(items__content_type__pk=ctype.pk)`.

Now, this never happens right after the restart. It attacks with surprise and starts messing up requests to a gunicorn worker (all requests with affected queries raise the error). Restarting the application helps. Obviously I can't reproduce it. Sometimes it fixes itself after an hour or two. I've read many threads about the same exception, but none of them seems to be related to my problem.

Some actual code (shortened a little):

```
def create_intermediary_table_model(model):
    """Create an intermediary table model for the specific tag model"""
    name = model.__name__ + 'Relation'

    class Meta:
        db_table = '%s_relation' % model._meta.db_table
        unique_together = (('tag', 'content_type', 'object_id'),)
        app_label = model._meta.app_label

    # Set up a dictionary to simulate declarations within a class
    attrs = {
        '__module__': model.__module__,
        'Meta': Meta,
        'tag': models.ForeignKey(model, related_name='items'),
        'content_type': models.ForeignKey(ContentType),
        'object_id': models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True),
        'content_object': GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id'),
    }

    return type(name, (models.Model,), attrs)


class TagMeta(ModelBase):
    """Metaclass for tag models (models inheriting from TagBase)."""
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        model = super(TagMeta, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)
        if not model._meta.abstract:
            # Create an intermediary table and register custom managers for concrete models
            model.intermediary_table_model = create_intermediary_table_model(model)
        return model


class TagBase(models.Model):
    """Abstract class to be inherited by model classes."""
    __metaclass__ = TagMeta

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Tag(TagBase):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=120, db_index=True)
```

The `Tag` class sits in another django app, if that matters.

Comment: Your post is a bit contradicting. You mention a M2M, but all I see is a ForeignKey. You're gonna have to show all relations in order for us to make *any* educated guesses. Maybe that also shows why you couldn't solve the problem using content types.

Comment: You're right, I don't know what I was thinking. I fixed the obvious mistake. It's hard to show all relations when one model is created dynamically by a metaclass of another model, but I'll try soon.

Comment: In fact `create_intermediary_table_model` was used only once, so I've replaced it with normal `class`. Over half a year passed and the problem hasn't returned, so I guess it's fixed. But no idea why exactly it happened.